# Scaling RabbitMQ-based microservices in Nestjs

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

I need to create a RabbitMQ-based microservices solution in Nestjs. To scale the system, I need to deploy several instances (e.g., 3 dockers) of the same microservice (server) listening to the same RabbitMQ topic, processing requests coming from the consumer (client) (see the following figure). I assume these 3 instances use a kind of Round Robin to pop up messages/requests from the queue/topic and process them and then return the results in another queue (i.e., 'callback' queue) to the consumer. I am wondering if

1. Nestjs already handles the correlation_id (to correlate responses with requests | to tackle the issue, having received a response in that queue it's not clear to which request the response belongs.) under the hood, or do I need to extend the current library?
2. Does NestJs create an exclusive callback queue (when several instances of the same microservices are deployed) or do I need to take care of that myself in my code (i.e., The worker (aka: server | microservice) is waiting for requests on that queue. When a request appears, it does the job and sends a message with the result back to the Client/Consumer, using the queue from the reply_to field.). In other words, The client (consumer) waits for data on the callback queue. When a message appears, it checks the correlation_id property. If it matches the value from the request it returns the response to the application.

[image]